# A4 size output with a0poster; A0 size only in combination with certain packages

Tags: paper-size, a0poster

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a0,landscape]{a0poster}
\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

When I compile this, I get A4 size output.

```
$ pdflatex foo.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 22 language(s) loaded.
(texmf/tex/latex/a0poster/a0poster.cls
Document Class: a0poster 2004/01/31 v1.22b a0poster class (GK, MW)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(texmf/tex/latex/a0poster/a0size.sty)) (./foo.aux) [1
Non-PDF special ignored!
<special> header=./a0header.ps
Non-PDF special ignored!
<special> papersize=118.82cm,83.96cm
{texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./foo.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/20
18basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb>
Output written on foo.pdf (1 page, 9922 bytes).
Transcript written on foo.log.

$ open foo.pdf # Shows 8.27 x 11.7 inches document

$ sips --getProperty all foo.pdf
/Users/lone/foo.pdf
  pixelWidth: 1240
  pixelHeight: 1753
  typeIdentifier: com.adobe.pdf
  format: pdf
  formatOptions: default
  dpiWidth: 150.000
  dpiHeight: 150.000
  samplesPerPixel: 4
  bitsPerSample: 8
  hasAlpha: yes
  space: RGB
  profile: sRGB IEC61966-2.1

$ echo "scale=2; 1240 / 150; 1753 / 150" | bc
8.26
11.68
```

What am I doing wrong that the final output is A4 even when A0 was requested?

By the way, a strange thing I notice is that the moment I use the `hyperref` or `graphicx` or `xcolor` package in the preamble, I get the desired A0 output (46.78 x 33.06 inches). For example:

```
\documentclass[a0,landscape]{a0poster}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

But importing some other package such as `multicol` or `titlesec` still leads to A4 size output. What is going on here?

Comment: The packages you mention load the needed driver file.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks! Your comment gave me a clue. Now I am using the command `latex foo.tex && dvipdf foo.dvi` to generate A0 size PDF output. Is there anyway to load the correct driver in my LaTeX source code itself so that I can continue to use the `pdflatex foo.tex` command to generate my PDF?

Comment: Just load ` graphicx`?